# Хлебные крошки рекурсивно из категорий в xml

Tags: php, xml, рекурсия

О рекурсии я знаю не очень много, но думаю так можно получить нужный результат с меньшим кодом. Есть `xml` с категориями:

```
<CatalogPackage>
  <Category>
    <Names>
       <Name Language="ru">Одежда</Name>
    </Names>
    <Children> 
    <Category IsParentOnProvider="true">
      <ExternalId>16</ExternalId>
      <Names>
         <Name Language="ru">Женская одежда</Name>
      </Names>
      <Children>
        <Category>
             <ExternalId>50010850</ExternalId>
             <Names>
                <Name Language="ru">Платья, сарафаны</Name>
             </Names>
            <Children>
            <Category>
             <ExternalId>5678</ExternalId>
               <Names>
                 <Name Language="ru">Сарафаны</Name>
               </Names>
             </Category>
             </Children>
        </Category>
      </Children>
     </Category>
      </Children>
  </Category>

  <Category>
    <Names>
       <Name Language="ru">Обувь</Name>
    </Names>
    <Children> 
    <Category IsParentOnProvider="true">
      <ExternalId>569</ExternalId>
      <Names>
         <Name Language="ru">Женская обувь</Name>
      </Names>
      <Children>
        <Category>
             <ExternalId>50012027</ExternalId>
             <Names>
                <Name Language="ru">Туфли</Name>
             </Names>
        </Category>
      </Children>
     </Category>
      </Children>
  </Category>
</CatalogPackage>
```

Возможно ли получить из этого файла, получит хлебные крошки, независимо от вложенности, передав функции `id` категории? Например я делаю так:

```
$languages = simplexml_load_file("categories.xml");
    function crumitem($json,$catid){
        if(isset($json->Children)){
            foreach($json->Children->Category as $valueperent){
                echo $valueperent->Names->Name.'<br />';
            }
        }else{
            foreach($json->Category as $value){
                echo '-'.$value->Names->Name.'<br />';
                foreach($value->Children->Category as $valueperent){
                    echo '--'.$valueperent->Names->Name.'<br />';
                    crumitem($valueperent,$catid);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    crumitem($languages,569); // Обувь > Женская обувь
```

и функция работает только до 3 уровня, и то не могу получать хлебные крошки
помогите строит хлебные крошки народ.

Answer (score 2):

На XQuery с рекурсией это может выглядеть так:

```
declare function local:recursion( $node as element() ) as xs:string {
 if ( $node/parent::* )
 then ( 
  local:recursion( $node/parent::* ) || "/" || $node/name() 
 )
 else ( $node/name() )
};


let $data := 
  <a>
    <b></b>
    <b>
      <c>
        <c/>
      </c>
    </b>
    <c/>
  </a>
for $node in $data//c
return  local:recursion( $node )
```

Результат:

```
a/b/c
a/b/c/c
a/c
```